# i want to use multiprocessing here instead of kthreads but for some reason it aint working

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
    def subtask():
            model = Model("model-en")
            rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)

        # Opens microphone for listening.
            p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
            stream.start_stream()
        
            while True:
                data = stream.read(1024)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    break
                if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                # result is a string
                    result = rec.Result()
                # convert it to a json/dictionary
                    result = json.loads(result)
                    text = result['text']
                
                    print(text)
                    query = text
                if "alarm" in query:
                    pass
                    
    
                    
                    
                    
                
        t2 = kthread.KThread(target = subtask, name = "main task")
    t2.start()
    
    def lol():
        model = Model("model-en")#next line
        rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)#next line

        # Opens microphone for listening.
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
    
        stream.start_stream()
        
        while True:
            data = stream.read(1024)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                # result is a string
                result = rec.Result()
                # convert it to a json/dictionary
                result = json.loads(result)
                text = result['text']
                
                print(text)
                query = text
                if 1==1:
                    if 1==1:
                        if 1==1:
                            if 1==1:
                                if 1==1:
                                    
                                    
                                    try:
                                        
                                    

                                    
                                    
                                        question = query
                                        # App id obtained by the above steps 
                                        app_id = "api key"#add it  

                                        # Instance of wolf ram alpha 
                                        # client class 
                                        client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id) 

                                        # Stores the response from 
                                        # wolf ram alpha 
                                        res = client.query(question) 

                                        # Includes only text from the response 
                                        answer = next(res.results).text 

                                        print(answer)
                                    except:
                                        print("could not find the answer")
                                    
                                        
        
        

    t3 = kthread.KThread(target = lol, name = "new task")#next line
    t3.start()
```

1.so what i am trying to achieve here is run both these codes parallely using multiprocessing module and since there are no args which have to be added i think it makes that trickier
as you can see i used the kthread module which is a countrfeit version of thread but is killable but when i replace k threade with multiprocessing.process random exceptions occur

Comment: Hello, welcome! Could you help clarify your question by adding punctuation to your question? For me as a non-native speaker it's hard to read.

Comment: 1.so what i am trying to achieve here is run both these codes parallely using multiprocessing module and since there are no args which have to be added, i think it makes that trickier as you can see i used the kthread module (which is a countrfeit version of threads) but is killable but when i replace k threads with multiprocessing.process random exceptions occur